# What's the utility of showing $\varphi(1 \otimes 1) = 1$ when proving $R[X] \otimes_R R[Y] \cong R[X, Y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

In Keith Conrad's [notes on tensor products](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf), in Example 7.7 he shows $\varphi: R[X] \otimes_R R[Y] \to R[X, Y]$ is an $R$-algebra isomorphism. For that, he shows $\varphi(1 \otimes 1) = 1$ first. I don't see the point of this. Is $1 \otimes 1$ a generator of $R[X] \otimes_R R[Y]$? If so, how?

Since $R[X] \otimes_R R[Y]$ is bilinear in only $R$, I think the only elements $1 \otimes 1$ can "generate" are of the form $R(1 \otimes 1)$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ring homomorphism must preserve units. That‘s all he‘s checking.

Comment: Ah, darn. Right, of course. Thanks!